# Running WinSCP script for Data transfer automation from remote to local

Tags: batch-file, sftp, winscp

I wrote a code to transfer data from remote drive to local drive. However, I am getting an error

> Scripting does not use standalone parameters. The parameters you have specified on command-line will not be used. Your command-line syntax is probably wrong.
> Opening session using command-line parameter in scripting is deprecated. Use 'open' command instead.
> Host:
> Host:

Appreciate your support.

Code

```
option batch abort
option confirm off
open sftp://username:password@server -hostkey="host key"
synchronize local "\\Local Path" 
/remote path
exit
```

Then I created a bat file,

```
winscp.com/SMS_BASES_SAMBA_TO DRIVE.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't really explain us, what did you intend to achieve with this:

```
winscp.com/SMS_BASES_SAMBA_TO DRIVE.txt
```

So I can only guess that the `SMS_BASES_SAMBA_TO DRIVE.txt` is a filename of your WinSCP script.

If that's correct, then the right syntax is:

```
winscp.com /script="SMS_BASES_SAMBA_TO DRIVE.txt"
```

That is:

- Use [`/script` switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#scripting) to specify the script file
- Wrap the filename to double quotes, as it contains a space.

---

Additionally, [it's recommended to add `/ini=nul` and `/log=...`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#script_file).

---

Note that you have the `synchronize` command broken into two lines. It should be one line only and the remote path should be quoted too (if it has spaces):

```
synchronize local "\\Local Path" "/remote path"
```